# Adding line breaks to a bare string (PHP)

Tags: php, text

Say if I want to dynamically download a text file from my website containing information from the database I would use something like:

```
$name = $_GET["download"];
$file = get_file_data($name);
if ($file) {
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file["custom_name"].".txt");
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    echo $file["stuff"];
    exit();
}
```

Where `$file["stuff"]` is a bare string of text read straight from the database.

However there don't seem to be any explicit line breaks in the stored text, instead when shown bare they look like large spaces between paragraph blocks.

(Of course when displayed in a `pre` tag on an HTML page the line breaks are there, because of `pre`'s CSS in most modern browsers.)

E.g.

```
The Last Question by Isaac Asimov &copy; 1956          The last question was asked for the first time, half in jest, on May 21, 2061, at a time when humanity first stepped into the light. The question came about as a result of a five dollar bet over highballs, and it happened this way:
```

How can I loop over any string like this and enforce `PHP_EOL` at the end of each line?

Comment: What are *large spaces*? Multiple spaces, tabs, etc.?

Comment: Well, line breaks do appear when the strings are in `pre` tags in HTML so perhaps there are line breaks but they are being interpreted as tabs by Windows Notepad, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `\n` to the string. But make sure it is added in double quotes. Example:

```
echo "Line 1 \n Line 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

get_file_data is a wordpress function, so I'm not sure if that what you want.

```
$name = $_GET["download"];
 //... sanitize the input first.
$thetext = file_get_contents($name); 

if($thetext)
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filename) . "\"");
echo nl2br($thetext);
```

Comment: No, it's a function I've defined further up in the code. It uses a prepared statement to fetch data from the database.